# Showing that $\nabla (\alpha f) = \alpha \nabla f$ for constant $\alpha$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I want show that del of alpha times a vector function for is equal to alpha times del of fun using. Alphar  is a constant hence it should be factories out after finding partial derivetives,but how do I show this by applying the rules of differentiation.

Comment: What is your definition of $\nabla$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial (\alpha f)}{\partial x_{i}}=\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$

Comment: Del=id/dx+jd/dy+kd/dz

Comment: @Martin Mallambo Your definition for $\nabla$ needs to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial (\alpha f)}{\partial x_{i}} &=& f \cdot \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_{i}}+ \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} \\
                                           &=& 0+ \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\\
                                           &=& \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}
\end{eqnarray}